# Create List from a subarray without copying in java

Tags: java, arrays, list, data-structures

I'm trying to initialize an ArrayList from an Array, but just the subarray, given the original array and subarray start and end index.

I can only think of doing something like this to create a new list from the subarray:

```
Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i, j));
```

or just manually add elements to a list

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(k);
for (int i = left; i < left + k; i++) {
    result.add(arr[i]);
}
```

Which obviously isn't very pretty. Is there better way to do it by just passing in array and indexes?

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393)

Comment: @JarrodRoberson How's that relevant?

Comment: @JarrodRoberson thanks for the reminder. I updated the question to be more general.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Better" depends on your requirements, and use case. Since you suggested using `Arrays.asList(...)`, which returns a *fixed size* list, I will assume here that a fixed size list is sufficient for your needs.

Probably the fastest way would be to use

```
Arrays.asList(arr).subList(i, j);
```

This will be quick, because no elements are copied anywhere, and no iteration is performed. `Arrays.asList(arr)` essentially creates a list which is a wrapper for the original array, and `subList(...)` creates a list which is a view of the existing list.

The trade-off (there is always a trade-off) is that this retains a reference to the original array. So if you were generating a large number of large arrays, and wanted to keep a small slice of each one, this would be a poor choice from a memory-consumption perspective. (Conversely, if you had one large array, and wanted a large number of different slices of it, potentially overlapping, this would be a very memory-efficient approach as well as being fast.)

If memory considerations mean that you need to release any reference to the original array, then you are forced to copy elements to a new structure somehow. Probably the most efficient way to do this is to use the approach you suggested: `Arrays.copyOfRange(...)` basically delegates to `System.arrayCopy(...)`, which is essentially implemented natively on most systems (bulk copy of a contiguous chunk of memory), and then as before `Arrays.asList(...)` just creates a list wrapper for that new array. So in the scenario that you want to release the reference to the original array, your suggested

```
Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, i, j));
```

is probably the "best" approach.

Comment: The other trade-off is that the list returned by `Arrays.asList` is kind of immutable, i.e. you can't neither add nor remove elements from it, though you could set an element on a specific position.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Yes, indeed; I kind of assumed that met the OP's requirements as they suggested a solution using `Arrays.asList(...)`. But you're correct that that should be made explicit.